# Определение города пользователя средствами JS

Tags: javascript, геолокация

Использую такой `js-скрипт` для определения местонахождения пользователя:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
        $.getJSON("//ip-api.com/json/?lang=ru", function(data) {
        var data_body = "";
        $.each(data, function(k, v) {
            data_body += "<b>" + k + "</b> : <i>" + v + "</i><br />"; 
        });        
        $(".city").val(data.city);        
        // Google Map
        var locations = [
        [data_body, data.lat, data.lon, 2]  //Данные из IP API
        ];    
    });
```

И выдаю данные о городе пользователя в `input`:

```
<input type="text" class="city">
```

Всё работало, пока не установил `SSL-сертификат`. Теперь скрипт не работает, а в консоли выдаёт ошибку:

> GET https://ip-api.com/json/?lang=ru 0 ()

В чём может заключаться проблема и как это исправить?

Comment: В чем проблема в сертификате или в API? Какай URL вы использовали?

Comment: Дело в том, что для данного сервиса не настроен https-протокол. Если вы получаете данные по http-протоколу, то все работает прекрасно, в противном случае выкинет ошибку. Как только Вы установили себе ssl-сертификат и Ваш сервис стал доступен по https-протоколу, то и в рамках скрипта обращение к сторонним сервисам (без явного указания протокола) по умолчанию перевелось на https. Попробуйте явно указать в функции getJSON адрес с протоколом: `http://ip-api.com/json/?lang=ru`

Comment: Позволю себе добавить, что данный сервис определяет не местоположение пользователя, а расположение его провайдера. В случае с домашней сетью это ещё как-то Вам и поможет (по крайней мере Вы узнаете город пользователя), а вот по поводу пользователей, которые зайдут к Вам с использованием мобильной сети есть проблемы: к примеру, `МТС`зарегистрирована в Москве. И пусть я далеко не москвич, Ваш ресурс будет считать меня таковым

Comment: Фак. Явное указание не помогло. Я просто в js пока не так силён, чтобы использовать Яндекс.Карты. Я нашёл скрипт в песочнице Яндекса, определение местоположения пользователя, но как сделать так, чтобы адресс выводился в input, не знаю. Спасибо ребят за отзывы!

Comment: @Devilz я бы советовал Вам использовать встроенные методы получения геопозиции пользователя (что происходит с его разрешения, сие будет и морально, и технически правильно): `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => console.log(pos), error => console.log(error));` Объект `pos` (если пользователь разрешит Вам узнать, где он находится) позволит узнать Вам широту и долготу местонахождения посетителя сайта (`pos.coords.latitude` и `pos.coords.longitude`)

Comment: @Devilz могу чуть позже привести решение как раз с помощью API Яндекс карт, если Вам это поможет

Comment: @Kir_Antipov буду очень признателен!

Comment: @Devilz хорошо) Где-то вечером дам ответ, пока не за компом)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov да, конечно. Разумеется, если это не сильно Вас затруднит)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так как Вы упомянули, что не имеете ничего против использования `API Yandex Maps`, то привожу пример реализации поставленной задачи с помощью сего API:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (YMaps.location) // Проверяем, доступна ли геопозиция
    { 
        console.log("Longitude: " + YMaps.location.longitude); // Выведем долготу
        console.log("Latitude: " + YMaps.location.latitude);   // Выведем широту
        $(".country").val(YMaps.location.country); // Достанем в input страну
        $(".region").val(YMaps.location.region);   // Достанем в input регион (область)
        $(".city").val(YMaps.location.city)        // Достанем в input город
    } 
    else
        alert("Пожалуйста, разрешите доступ к использованию Вашей геопозиции!");
});
```

```css
input {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/1.1/index.xml" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="country" placeholder="Country">
    <input type="text" class="region" placeholder="Region">
    <input type="text" class="city" placeholder="City">
</form>
```

Прошу обратить Ваше внимание, что *обязательно* нужно поставить какой-нибудь обработчик на тот случай, если пользователь запрещает доступ к своей геопозиции, так как такие случаи весьма часты, и если Вам необходимо иметь о ней информацию, то вызовите какое-нибудь модальное окно, которое объяснит посетителю Вашего сайта, для чего же Вам нужно знать его местонахождение

---

К слову, как я уже писал в комментариях, узнать местоположение пользователя можно и встроенными методами (однако опять же пользователь *должен разрешить* такое вот вторжение в его частную жизнь))
Делается это так:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
        console.log("Longitude: " + pos.coords.longitude); // Выведем долготу
        console.log("Latitude: " + pos.coords.latitude);   // Выведем широту
}, error => console.log("Пожалуйста, разрешите доступ к использованию Вашей геопозиции!"));
```

---

Надеюсь, мой ответ помог Вам разрешить вставшую пред Вами задачу) Удачи в Ваших начинаниях!

Comment: огромное спасибо Вам! А за дополнение отдельное спасибо)

Comment: @Devilz Если ответ подошёл Вам, то отметьте галочкой)